# GORMのFindを使ってDBの中身を取得したが、すべて空になる

Tags: go, google-app-engine, gorm

ただいまGAE+CloudSQLを使って簡単なAPIを作っています。
DBの全データを取得できるAPIを実装しようとし、以下のコードを作りました。

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

type Person struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Age  int    `json:"age"`
}

var db *gorm.DB

func main() {
    db = DB()

    http.HandleFunc("/user", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        defer db.Close()
        var people []Person
        db.Find(&people)
        str, _ := json.Marshal(people)
        fmt.Printf("%s\n", str)
        return
    })

    port := os.Getenv("PORT")
    if port == "" {
        port = "8080"
        log.Printf("Defaulting to port %s", port)
    }

    log.Printf("Listening on port %s", port)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(fmt.Sprintf(":%s", port), nil))
}

func DB() *gorm.DB {
    var (
        connectionName = os.Getenv("CLOUDSQL_CONNECTION_NAME")
        user           = os.Getenv("CLOUDSQL_USER")
        password       = os.Getenv("CLOUDSQL_PASSWORD")
        socket         = os.Getenv("CLOUDSQL_SOCKET_PREFIX")
        databaseName   = os.Getenv("CLOUDSQL_DATABASE_NAME")
        option         = os.Getenv("CLOUDSQL_OPTION")
    )

    if socket == "" {
        socket = "/cloudsql"
    }
    if option == "" {
        option = "?parseTime=true"
    }

    dbURI := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s@unix(%s/%s)/%s%s", user, password, socket, connectionName, databaseName, option)
    conn, err := gorm.Open("mysql", dbURI)
    if err != nil {
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("DB: %v", err))
    }

    return conn
}
```

しかし、これを実装しAPIを叩くと、何も出力されません。
原因を調べてみると、
db.Find(&people)
のあとのpeopleが、配列の要素数はDBのデータ数と合っていましたが中身がすべて空文字や0になっていました。

実装に問題があるのか、GCPの設定に問題があるのかさっぱりわかりません。
どなたか解決策を教えてください。よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

すみません、簡単なミスをしていました。

```
http.HandleFunc("/user", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    defer db.Close()
    ~~~~
})
```

と書いていたので、この関数の実行が終わるとDB接続が切れてしまいますね。
コードを修正しdb.Close()をmain文直下に書くと、
person.Nameもperson.Ageも取得することができました。

Answer (score 0):

`Person`に

```
`gorm:"column:name"`
```

の形式でカラム名の指定がないため、データベースから取得した行を構造体にマッピングできず、すべての要素が空要素になったように見えますがいかがでしょうか？

https://gorm.io/docs/models.html